# pass php date to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

i'm making a code where when i selected a start date,an end date will automatically appear. the end date is +3 days of the start date

```
<input type="date" name="start_date" id="start" onKeyUp="date()">
<input type="text" name="end_date" id = "end" onKeyUp="date()" disabled />

<script type = "text/javascript">
function date() {
var startdate = document.getElementById('start');
var enddate = document.getElementById('end');

enddate.value = startdate + 3 days; 
}
</script>
```

this enddate.value = startdate + 3 days;  i know that code is wrong. i dont know how to pass dates to javascript. please help

Comment: I guess You need to create a date object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="num_days" id = "days"  />
<input type="date" name="start_date" id="start" onChange="date()">
<input type="text" name="end_date" id = "end" onKeyUp="date()"  />

    <script type = "text/javascript">
    function date() {
         var numdays = document.getElementById('days');
    var startdate = document.getElementById('start');
    var enddate = document.getElementById('end');
    //conver you selected stuff to a proper date format
    var old = new Date(Date.parse(startdate.value));
    //take a new date
    var newdate = new Date();
        days = parseInt(numdays.value);
    // add how many days you want to add i use 3 you can use as many
    newdate.setDate(old.getDate()+days);
    enddate.value = newdate.getFullYear()+'-'+(newdate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+newdate.getDate(); 
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: whats the problem you just want to pick a date and want to display 3 days ahead in right input box right?

Comment: i have edited my answer its working on my side.did you entered after picking up the date

Comment: still the same. i wonder what's the problem. i just copied the code that you gave to me.

Comment: i have added js fiddle pick a date when its done click on the same text box and enter on it

Comment: oh i see. so i need to enter first to get the value? hmm how to do it without pressing the enter and without the alert? i'm sorry i don't know much about javascript

Comment: oh it's just giving me the current date. it's not adding 3 days to the date

Comment: cool it's now working. my final question is how to format the date? like in Y-m-d

Comment: sir i have another question

Comment: ask it and post me the link

Comment: i added something on this code. what i did was i want the user to enter the number of days and then add it to the start date that he chose. this is the link http://jsfiddle.net/arukiri/bZ9m9/ but i was getting a value of Nan-Nan-Nan. i wonder why

Comment: whatever i do the value is still Nan-Nan-Nan. Please help :/

Comment: added new code in my answer..next time please raise a new question

Comment: sir i found an error. when i choose the start date march 27. it gives an end date of march 2. please help

Comment: i think the problem is the leap year. i don't know how to fix it. please help

Comment: sir this is the link about the error that i found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932630/javascript-dateleap-year

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the start date in the `date()`

```
var today = new Date(document.getElementById('start'));
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;//January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd
}
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm
}
var startdate=yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd ;
var enddate=yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+(parseInt(dd)+3) ;
```

This will give you 2 dates:

1. Start date
2. Start date + 3 days i.e enddate

I hope it will help you!

Comment: the dates are inputted by the user. i need to get the value inputted in the input date then pass it to js

Answer (score 0):

try it here [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mybidfix/ZuugH/2/)

```
function mydate() {
     var targetDate = new Date();
     targetDate.setDate(targetDate.getDate() + 3); //how many days ahead

     var dd = targetDate.getDate();
     var mm = targetDate.getMonth() + 1; // 0 is January, so we must add 1
     var yyyy = targetDate.getFullYear();
     var dateString = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
     return dateString; 
}
```

Comment: but the dates are inputted by the user. how can i get the value of date box then pass it to js?

Comment: yes it's working. it adds the 3days in the current date. but what i want to happen is the user will input the date

Comment: well are you using a form?

Comment: why don't you post the form so we can better assist you?

Comment: <input type="date" name="start_date" id="start" onKeyUp="date()">
<input type="text" name="end_date" id = "end" onKeyUp="date()" disabled />