# javascript date(leap year)

Tags: javascript

i have this code where the user inputs the start date and then it will automatically add the end date. the end date is +3 days to the start date. the problem is after the month of february, march26-31 and so outputs wrong end date. it always output wrong end date from 26-31.  i think the problem is the leap year but i don't know how to fix it. please help me.

this is the code:

```
<input type="date" name="start_date" id="start" onKeyUp="date()">
<input type="text" name="end_date" id = "end" onKeyUp="date()" disabled />
        <script type = "text/javascript">
function date() {
var startdate = document.getElementById('start');
var enddate = document.getElementById('end');
//conver you selected stuff to a proper date format
var old = new Date(Date.parse(startdate.value));
//take a new date
var newdate=new Date(Date.parse(startdate.value)+24*60*60*1000*3);
// add how many days you want to add i use 3 you can use as many
newdate.setDate(old.getDate()+3);
enddate.value = (newdate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+newdate.getDate()+'-'+newdate.getFullYear(); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `.setDate()` is applied on today's date in your code, so that wouldn't work properly. Both dates need to equal each other before you start doing date calculations.

```
var old = new Date(Date.parse(startdate.value)),
newdate = old;

newdate.setDate(old.getDate() + 3);
```

This will work fine for stuff like leap seconds as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var newdate=new Date(Date.parse(startdate.value)+24*60*60*1000*3);
```

Instead of directly manipulating upon the `getDate()` result.

**Edit**:

Explanation about the number:

```
  24            * 60               * 60                 * 1000                    * 3
//hours per day   minutes per hour   seconds per minute   milliseconds per second   3 days
```

Comment: ow there's a problem when i choose february 28,2013. it gives me an end date of 3/29/2013. how to fix this?

Comment: Days are not always 86400 seconds long.

Comment: @Jack While in "standard time" it's true, I'm unaware that JS interpreters take that into account. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Passerby no sir. its february 28 2013, and it gives me an end date of march 29,2013. the end date is just +3 to the start date. so it should be march 3 2013

Comment: @arukiri123 Oops, sorry, mis-read your comment. I didn't get your result. I get 2013-03-03 on both Chrome and Firefox. What browser are you testing on?

Comment: @Passerby Leap seconds for instance, though contrived, is one good example why you should let JavaScript figure out how long a day really is :)

Comment: @Passerby im using chrome sir

Comment: @Jack Yes I know there're Leap Seconds in "standard time", but can you provide an example that makes JS "admits" 24:00:00? I always thought interpreters will simply assumed 86400 on every day.

Comment: @Passerby oh when i also choose march 31,2013 it gives me an end date of may 4,2013. all months with dates of 30 and 31 have the same problem. it adds 2months

Comment: @arukiri123 Are you sure your date string actually got parsed as 2013-02-28? Try to `console.log` both values to make sure everything is expected.

Comment: @arukiri123 I tested `new Date(Date.parse("2013-02-28")+24*60*60*1000*3)` and correctly got `2013-03-03`. What's your input date format?

Comment: it's now working sir. i used newdate = old; everything is fine now. thank you for the help

Comment: @arukiri123 I tested `new Date(Date.parse("31 march, 2013")+24*60*60*1000*3)` and still correctly got 2013-04-03. Try to change `24*60*60*1000*3` to `259200*1000` and see if it works.